# .less prebuild event command throws errors

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, less

I've added a prebuild event command to my project solution that calls the .less (dotless) compiler to compile my .less files:

```
"$(SolutionDir)packages\dotless.1.4.0.0\tool\dotless.compiler.exe" -m "$(ProjectDir)Assets\Style\source\bootstrap\bootstrap.less" "$(ProjectDir)Assets\Style\css\bootstrap.css"
```

When I run the command in the Windows command prompt, it runs fine and the .css file gets builded. However, when I build the solution, Visual Studio throws an error:

```
... exited with code 9009
```

Which seems to be a generic error telling *'something is wrong'*. Paths are correct, the prebuild environment variables can correctly be resolved.

Comment: please post relevant output of the Output Window. Also if you do a search you'll notice it's not really a generic error but rather means "file not found"

Comment: @stijn To specify, it means *something not found*. That might also be an environment variable etc. The relevant output is basically what I posted above - the error. Before that, I have just the command (with the resolved paths), which are correct.

Comment: no it means file not found (as in `is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file`), and yes that *might* be the result of a missing environment variable. Or a typo. Or the fact that the file does not exist. Sure what you posted is also relevant, but what is in the output window is what is *really* relevant as it might reveal missing quotes/spaces etc. Does your command execute properly when pasted on a command line? Only then you know it's really correct.

Comment: @stijn  *Does your command execute properly when pasted on a command line* - surprisingly, it does. That's why I'm confused.